# how to design mat-toolbar full width of the screen

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design, angular6

Here, I am using `Angular-Material` in which my environment are : `Angular CLI: 6.0.5` , `Node: 10.1.0`, `OS: win32 x64`, `Angular: 6.0.3` and I want the output like this:
[image]

To implement exactly same top nav bar I have `mat-toolbar` as follows:

**In .html**

```
 <mat-toolbar class="topbar telative mat-toolbar mat-primary mat-toolbar-single-row" color="primary"  ng-reflect-color="primary" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;position: fixed;" [class.mat-elevation-z24]="isActive">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon> 
    </button>
    <h1 class="example-app-name">Admin Panel</h1>
 </mat-toolbar>
```

**In .ts**

I simply have one property for isActive

```
 isActive = true;
```

My output is absolutely fine but the `mat-toolbar` does not cover the full width of screen as a result the vertical scroll bar is coming just in side of `mat-toolbar`. I want to have is scroll bar below my `mat-toolbar` as in the image above. How can I set the width of `mat-toolbar` to full screen.

Comment: can you post an example of what you obtain?

Answer (score 6):

In your style.css add this`body{margin:0}`

Answer (score 4):

To set `mat-toolbar` width to 100% you can do similar in your css file

```
.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: when i do this, the header blocks the title of the other component. Its overlays over the other component. 

<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>